# %in% is not giving the right output

Tags: r

I have written the following code in Rstudio editor, and the builtin function %in% is not working as desired. At the third last iteration there is a match but %in% is not returning TRUE. Kindly help.

```
longi=c(5.044747,5.054746,9)
longdummypos=longi
incrementinx=0.000001
for (incx in seq(from=0, to=0.01, by=incrementinx))
{
 longdummypos=longdummypos+incrementinx
 print(longdummypos)
 print(longi)
  a=longdummypos %in% longi
  print(a)
  t1=is.element(TRUE,a)

    if(t1==TRUE)
    {
      break()
    }

    incrementinxfinal=incx  
}
```

Comment: If it is a floating point number, then there is precision and it may not exactly match

Comment: This is related to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272. In fact, since `%in%` is looking for *equality*, it's a dupe of that (in concept if not actual code). This problem is not unique to R, most languages that use "simple" IEEE-754 for floating-point storage and arithmetic are going to be prone to this problem.

Comment: Okay, @akrun, provide an answer that differs in context and point to the R FAQ and answer that I linked. *"Selective dupe tagging"* is by design: I selectively tag as dupe questions that I feel are dupes, not sure what point you're trying to make.

Comment: The issue is not clear.  When I commented, it is only based on some assumptions

Comment: @r2evans  i have checked %in% in another simple example in console,and it is working perfectly fine upto 6 decimal places (my desired accuracy). The problem occurs when i use it inside the for loop.

Comment: There is not a match on the fourth iteration. On the fourth iteration, I see: "[1] 5.044751 5.054750 9.000004
[1] 5.044747 5.054746 9.000000
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE" No match there

Comment: @duckmayr Sorry i made a mistake. It's the third last iteration

Comment: @r2evans . But it is working perfectly fine when the same values of the particular (third  last)iteration are tested in the console window seperately.

Comment: Faraz, testing equality of floating-point numbers works some or perhaps even most of the time, but the premise of testing true equality (in most programming languages) is flawed due to how numbers are stored internally. You need to determine a *tolerance* of effectively-equal numbers, perhaps if `abs(a-b) < 1e-8`. It will often work fine, but it is not guaranteed to work all of the time.

Comment: Faraz, instead of base R's `%in%`, consider using this quick hack: `\`%isin%\` <- function(a, b, tol = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) rowSums(abs(outer(a, b, \`-\`)) < tol) > 0` instead.

Comment: Better yet, add `na.rm=TRUE` to the `rowSums` call ...

Comment: While this is a common question, it is still a duplicate in the premise of equality (and therefore set-membership). Do you have enough help and context to be able to close this question?

Comment: @r2evans. Yes, I got the solution for the problem. Thankyou very much for helping.

Comment: @akrun, it's been clearly resolved as the same issue as discussed early in the comments. Since I closed and then reopened, I cannot close it as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272. Would you please close it as a dupe?

Comment: @r2evans closed now